# Large number of distribution maps - Batch maps / Atlas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, batch, atlas

I try to make distribution maps for about 500 species.
In the orginal file all species / points are in one shapefile, via the tombio productivity tool-pluging I separated the species and created simple maps.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iq6UWPcH46k&feature=youtu.be)

However I need the maps with title, number of features etc. in it and publication quality.

I found 
[Batch maps (atlas plugin style) in same location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28830/qgis-batch-maps-atlas-plugin-style-in-same-location)
and 
[How to create an Atlas based on point attributes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155278/how-to-create-an-atlas-based-on-point-attributes/156023#156023)

but none of these seem suitable for the high number of species.

The result should be the ca. 500 maps with the possibilty to add text fields with expressions from the shapefile.

Is there "simple" solution in Qgis via the atlas generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found following workaround:

1. Transform the single-point geometry with the species data in a multi-point geometry with the species as "categories" via spatialite (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170472/merge-single-points-to-multi-point-geometry/170474#170474)), which enables me also to calculate number of individuals, number of samples an numer of localities.
2. Save data as shapefile
3. Prepare map composer: add a map controlled by atlas generation
4. cover this map completly with a second map which is the "overview" (not controlled by atlas) and set transparency of the red square to 100% (invisible), now the view should be static in all maps.

5.Go to main window: layer poperties -> style -> rule based -> set rule to $id=@atlas_featureid ($id from records, @atlas_featureid form variables) see [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/automating_map_creation.html), step 24-28.

6. Now only one species per map is displayed in the print composer atlas generation and species name, number of individuals etc. can be added to map via expressions.