# Merge single points to multi point geometry

Tags: qgis, point, spatialite, geometry-conversion, multipart

Is it possible to transform a point shapefile in single part geometry to a shapefile with multi-point geometry based on an attribute.
e.g. in the file are 50.000 records in 700 categories, now I want to create a multi-part geometry point file.

The result should be a shapefile with 700 records (=categories in the former shape).

Is this possible in QGIS, Spatialite or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do this through default top menu:

**Vector - Geometry Tools - Singleparts to Multipart...**

Though above the input there is written "Input line or polygon vector layer" I just tested it with point layer and it did work.

Also once you create multipoint layer to edit - add / delete parts (point from multipoint) you need to use **Advanced Digitizing** (right click on top bar to activate it) and use tools **Add Part / Delete Part**.

Comment: When I do singleparts to multiparts I only get an empty shape file

Comment: @user16032 I just checked with another file and it worked smooth again, are you sure you are doing it on the proper column and there are no null values in that column (which might cause issues)?

Comment: there was one hidden NULL, never checked, seems to works now, incredibel slow but it works. thanks a lot for the tip with the NULL!

Comment: It appears that the "Singleparts to Multiparts" function doesn't exist in version 3.8 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I guess it is possible (with spatialite at least).
In spatialite for example you probably can do something like:
`CREATE TABLE yournewtable AS SELECT group_concat(foo), CastToMultiPoint(Gunion(GEOMETRY)) FROM your50000recordstable GROUP BY your700categories_column`
which should result in 700 multipoint features (1 per category), with `GEOMETRY` as your geometry column and where `group_concat(foo)` will take the value of `foo` column for each record of each category and concatenate them.

Comment: The creation of the table works, categories are ok, but when loaded in Qgis the geometry column is empty / NULL. any idea why? thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you recover the geometry column after the CREATE statment ? If not you should : `SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn('your_table', 'GEOMETRY', the_srid, 'Multipoint', 'XY');`

Comment: (it should return 1 if it succeed or 0 if it fails)

Comment: Tried something around, it worked via "Create table newtable as select distinct (Category), aswkt(casttomultipoint(gunion(geometry))) FROM Database
Group by (Category)" and then import in Qgis. thanks lot!

Answer (score 1):

Vector - Geometry Tools - Singleparts to Multipart... this pluging doesn´t exist more for the QGIS new versions.
What do you have to do? Create a new column and concatenate records with categories and them dissolve this column, result a new shape multipoint,  that's all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).